# Admob for iOS interstitial video runs in background when loaded

Tags: ios, admob

I load the intersitial ad on the load of the controller. When the load finished, ad starts running automatically. The sound of the ad is heard. The load code is below:

```
interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:admobInterstatialID];
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
[interstitial loadRequest:request];
```

The show ad code is below:

```
if ([interstitial isReady]) {
    [interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've got the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @bartl nope, not yet :/

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Check logs to see if you are getting error "Cannot present interstitial. It is not ready."

Is below code written inside load of controller?

```
if ([interstitial isReady]) {
    [interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

You need wait till ad is loaded completely ( Specially for interstitial ads). 
Please change code to

```
    - (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad { 
if ([interstitial isReady]) {
    [interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

}

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I can present the ad, this is not the problem. The problem is; without calling presentFromRootViewController the ad starts running automatically

Comment: i see snipet of if ([interstitial isReady]) {
    [interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
} above. I thought that is called from load controller.

Comment: The problem is the ad starts before if ([interstitial isReady]) { [interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self]; } code.